# DBLINK Name as a variable oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, dblink

I had a problem while using dblink in oracle apex. I Have Created 3 Dblinks to 3 different remote database,[DBLINKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTuvr.png)

Now I want the below LOV's to be cascaded from the dblinks. So What should the write in the query as the name of dblink is a variable.[Query for LOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWJL5.png)

Thanks.

Comment: YOu can't do that.  In pl/sql you can use execute immediate, but I don't know how that works with apex.

Comment: I tried execute immediate but also generated error, is there any way where I can put variable in after "SELECT * FROM dba_roles@xxxx" in the xxx position?

Comment: What error did it generate? Please post the code so we may assist effectively. Please post all relevant info when posting questions.

Comment: You can, but that would create a security concern. I'd go with LittleFoot's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the item you use to select a *database* is named `P1_DATABASE` and its source is

```
select database_name d, database_id r
from list_of_databases
order by database_id;
```

and returns

```
DBLINK1, 1
DBLINK2, 2
DBLINK3, 3
```

as display/return values.

Create a LoV that utilizes `UNION`, such as

```
select role d, role r 
  from dba_roles@dblink1
  where :P1_DATABASE = 1
union all
select role d, role r 
  from dba_roles@dblink2
  where :P1_DATABASE = 2
union all
select role d, role r 
  from dba_roles@dblink3
  where :P1_DATABASE = 3;
```

which means: if you select `dblink1`, its return value is `1` so the first `SELECT` will return some values, while 2nd and 3rd won't. The same goes for other options you choose.

That's the general idea; modify it if necessary.

Comment: This reduces security issues associated with alternative solutions. I would go a step further and define that as a view.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have managed to do it by DBMS_UTILITY.DDL_STATEMENT

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you did it. If it is not a problem, could you describe what you exactly did and why you chose to use this package?

Answer (score 0):

Use "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query" then in the plsql you can build up the specific one you need based on inputs.

Along the lines of this>

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(2000) := '';
begin
  if ( :P1_DATABASE = 1 ) then
    v_sql := 'select blah from blah@db1';
  elsif ( :P1_DATABASE = 2 ) then
    v_sql := 'select blah from blah@db2';
  elsif ( :P1_DATABASE = 3 ) then
    v_sql := 'select blah from blah@db3';
  end if;

  return v_sql;
end;
```

[image]